# Cloth simulation doesn't work with collision

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have simple model, just legs and pants, when pressed play animation pants mesh goes up to the pined mesh part. I played with cloth simulation and collision values but result always the same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes. Also cranked up the quality settings a bit so if your pc can't handle it, just pull those back a little.
I have pinned the top and some other simple settings. I also changed the shape of the legs very slightly so the pants wouldn't pass through on some places.
[The edited blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/?pk7lckheeykan1n)

Comment: Can you tell more what cause the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I immediately deleted the cloth and collision physics and set them up all over again.